# C# call MDI child from child form

Tags: c#, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

I have these forms:

MainScreen - *MDI container*
DataBaseOutput - *child*
NewAnime - *child*

DataBaseOutput has a tab control that holds datagrids, each for different tables. I use an access database.

In those tabs, there is a menustrip, where the functions "New", "Edit", "Delete" etc. will be called from. Now when I'm on the first tab's menustrip and click on "New" I want to open the form "NewAnime", inside the MDI container. This however, is not working as I planned. At first I tried to just call it from the childform (DataBaseOutput). This resulted in opening a new form instead of a child. when I made it a child it was not showing up.

Then I triend lots of things, but I still haven't figured it out.

This is the current code for calling the form. It calls the form with a method in the main form:

```
private void NewAnime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainScreen main = new MainScreen();
    main.mShowForm(2);

    this.Close();
}
```

Method in the main form:

```
// Forms for MDI Parent
DataBaseOutput OutputForm = new DataBaseOutput();
NewAnime AddAnime = new NewAnime();

// How i made them childs (this is at the InitializeComponent(); part)
OutputForm.MdiParent = this;
AddAnime.MdiParent = this;

public void mShowForm(int formnumber)
{
    switch (formnumber)
    {
        case 1: OutputForm.Show(); break;
        case 2: AddAnime.Show(); break;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a clue of what i'm doing wrong and maybe has a better idea? This might be a bit too much working around, but as I said, it's my first time using MDI forms and i'm just trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the `MainForm` to be an `MDIContainer`? To do this set its [IsMdiContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.ismdicontainer%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) property to true; Also check it has `File` and `Window` top-level menu items and `New` and `Close` menu items. (The tutorial suggests this, I know it should have a `Window` menu item at least).

Have a look at this tutorial for more guidance: [Creating MDI Child Forms (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984329%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

**EDIT:** Looking at it more closely, it seems you are creating a new instance of MainForm, and trying to show the form as a child of that instance, as opposed to showing it in the existing MainForm. I assume you already have an instance of MainForm open at this point? And assuming the OutputForm and AddAnime forms are children of MainForm you could call the existing instance's method like this:

```
private void NewAnime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ParentForm.mShowForm(2);
    this.Close();
}
```

but ideally you should have an event on DataBaseOutput that MainForm listens to, and shows the new Form when the event is raised. See here for more info *(it talks about user controls and not child forms, but the principle is the same)*:

[Calling parent form functions from a user control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/agusercontrol.aspx)

Comment: Yes, it is an MDIContainer and it's all there. The idea is to open a new child (AddAnime) and fill it in, then close it again, but I want it inside the MDIContainer. 
Anyway, I need to call a new child from a child, and I can't seem to make that happen properly. I can call a child from the main form, it works, but I can't call the child from the other child.

Comment: @ your edit: Ok, thanks, but where do i need to show the DataBaseOutput form that MainForm is it's parentform? because I can't run it right now.